# Getting values from dialog custom layout

Tags: java, android, layout, dialog

I want to know how i will be able to reference and get values of views from a layout added to a `DialogFragment`
I was able to add a layout xml to my DialogFragment like this

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
    // Add action buttons
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.signin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // sign in the user ...
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
               }
           });
    return builder.create();
}
```

I implement the DialogFragment class with it's interface like this

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
                          implements NoticeDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener{
    ...

    public void showNoticeDialog() {
        // Create an instance of the dialog fragment and show it
        DialogFragment dialog = new NoticeDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "NoticeDialogFragment");
    }

    // The dialog fragment receives a reference to this Activity through the
    // Fragment.onAttach() callback, which it uses to call the following methods
    // defined by the NoticeDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener interface
    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // User touched the dialog's positive button
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // User touched the dialog's negative button
        ...
    }
}
```

This is my custom layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialog_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dim_large"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_rectangle_transparent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You already having an interface . Just add a method and call it on action . If you want to read it from Activity you can get the current object of `DialogFragment ` and provide a getter for values .

Comment: @ADM can you writ a sample code on how to do it?

Comment: Try calling `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("NoticeDialogFragment")` . This will return the current object of fragment if its attached . After that you can call any method of this fragment .

Comment: @ADM what I did was reference the view using inflater, then pass the string value of the edit text through the interface

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to parse string value of `Dialog` `EditText` to my `Activity`

```
/* The activity that creates an instance of this dialog fragment must
 * implement this interface in order to receive event callbacks.
 * Each method passes the DialogFragment in case the host needs to query it. */
public interface DialogListener {
    void onConfirmPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, String password);
    void onConfirmNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}
```

`onCreateDialog` I referenced the view using `LayoutInflater`

```
// Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_edit_text, null);
```

Then on positive click listener I reference `EditText` from view, get String value of `EditText` and parse it into the positive click listener

```
.setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_edit_text);
                    String password = editText.getText().toString();
                    // Send the positive button event back to the host activity
                    mListener.onConfirmPositiveClick(ConfirmationDialog.this, password);
                }
            })
```